# MySQL Select if Timestamp is in the past

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a database like this:

```
TABLE
Name               |            timestamp
------------------------------------------
Hello              |            2013-02-23 14:26:18
Yo                 |            2013-03-22 14:26:18
```

I want to do a SQL Select where only things that are in the past (e.g. the timestamp isn't set for the future) are selected.

What would be the best way to do that?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

I tried the suggestions but none of them seem to work, here is the query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE timestamp<NOW()
```

And it still selected everything, I also tried:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE timestamp<CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And it still selected everything again.

It's really wierd, when I use "timestamp>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" it seems to work (it hides all items not from the future) but not when I try the other direction which makes no sense. Could it be a timezone issue or something like that?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT `Name` FROM `TABLE` WHERE `timestamp` < NOW();
```

Should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE timestamp<now();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE 'timestamp' < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: It's really wierd, the reverse of this works.  (ex SELECT * FROM Table WHERE timestamp>CURRENT_TIMESTAMP).  That shows only items from the future.  But if I try the reverse of that it shows everything, it makes no sense and I can't figure out why.

Comment: @Talon what is the datatype of your column 'timestamp' ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourtable T
WHERE T.timestamp < NOW();
```

...?

[`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) ...

> Returns the current date and time as a value in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'
>   or YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu format, depending on whether the function is
>   used in a string or numeric context. The value is expressed in the
>   current time zone.

Comment: It's really wierd, the reverse of this works. (ex SELECT * FROM Table WHERE timestamp>NOW() ). That shows only items from the future. But if I try the reverse of that it shows everything, it makes no sense and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Try `SELECT NOW();` to see the servers current time.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table where `timestamp` < now()
```